# Why are SSHD sessions being left open

Tags: linux, ssh

```
root      4612     1  0 Jan26 ?        00:00:00 sshd: lp [priv]
sshd      4614  4612  0 Jan26 ?        00:00:00 sshd: lp [net]
root      4617     1  0 Jan26 ?        00:00:00 sshd: lp [priv]
sshd      4618  4617  0 Jan26 ?        00:00:00 sshd: lp [net]
root      4746     1  0 Jan28 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [priv]
sshd      4747  4746  0 Jan28 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [net]
root      5645     1  0 Feb01 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [priv]
sshd      5646  5645  0 Feb01 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [net]
root      6067     1  0 Jan30 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [priv]
sshd      6068  6067  0 Jan30 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [net]
root      6488     1  0 Jan27 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [priv]
sshd      6489  6488  0 Jan27 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [net]
root      6581     1  0 Jan29 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [priv]
sshd      6582  6581  0 Jan29 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [net]
root      6645     1  0 Feb02 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [priv]
sshd      6646  6645  0 Feb02 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [net]
root      6858     1  0 Jan25 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [priv]
sshd      6859  6858  0 Jan25 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [net]
root      7057     1  0 Jan26 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [priv]
sshd      7058  7057  0 Jan26 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [net]
root      7168     1  0 Jan28 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [priv]
sshd      7169  7168  0 Jan28 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [net]
root      7200     1  0 Jan23 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [priv]
root      7201     1  0 Jan23 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [priv]
root      7202     1  0 Jan23 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [priv]
root      7203     1  0 Jan23 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [priv]
sshd      7205  7200  0 Jan23 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [net]
sshd      7206  7201  0 Jan23 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [net]
sshd      7207  7202  0 Jan23 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [net]
sshd      7208  7203  0 Jan23 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [net]
root      7249     1  0 Jan23 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [priv]
sshd      7250  7249  0 Jan23 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [net]
root      7304     1  0 Jan30 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [priv]
sshd      7305  7304  0 Jan30 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [net]
root      8856     1  0 Jan29 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [priv]
```

My server is set to ban via IPTables on brute force attacks so how can I figure out why these SSHD sessions are remaining open?

Does this have to do with SFTP or FTPS

Comment: You should have a corresponding PID entry in your logs that show more information about the connection - /var/log/secure on Cent/RHEL.  To see more information about what sftp clients are doing, add "-l INFO" to your "Subsystem sftp" line in your sshd_config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this picture is typical for the bruteforce remains from scanner sessions, trying to get the access to your system. Usually they don't close the connection properly, so it remains open for quite some time, or, even more, they continue the authentication attempts using this connection. If your system logs contain lots of records like `error: PAM: authentication error for root from [...]` then this is it.

You should really consider using following techniques to get rid of them:

- use [Fail2Ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) software to block the scanners.
- write a simple script scanning your `messages` log seeking for the IP attackers addresses, and add them to blocking ACL of your packet filter to block the attacker access. Call it periodically with `cron`. I prefer this particular way of dealing with scanners.
- consider adding `PermitRootLogin no` to your `sshd_config`. Then use ordinary user accounts to log in, and then `sudo`/`su` to gain root access when needed. This way is way more secure than the default Linux approach. Furthermore, modern secure operating systems, like Solaris, FreeBSD or even some Linuxes do use this approach too - when the root account isn't a full-fledged system account, buth rather a role assigned to some of the users.